# Does the probability that at least one statistic will exhibit a "statistically significant" fluctuation converge to 1 as $N\rightarrow\infty$?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, central-limit-theorem

In the study and usage of statistics the idea that particular statistics will converge "almost certainly" to some value as the sample size $N$ diverges plays a key role (e.g. the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)). Thinking about the phenomenon of [$p$-hacking](http://psychology.wikia.com/wiki/P-hacking) has lead me to wonder: what are the limits of these theorems? Particularly, can this statement be proven:

> Considering the family of all statistics that converge almost certainly to some "true" value if the sample size $N\rightarrow\infty$ while the number of statistics $n$ are are fixed, if we let $n=f(N)\rightarrow\infty$ and maintain a fixed criterion for the significance of a statistic then the probability of a [type I error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Type_I_error) tends to 1.

What I mean by "family of statistics that converge almost certainly" is I'm only interested in the statistics where each statistic will converge to some "true" value almost certainly, when considered in isolation. And by "significant" I mean by any metric by which distance from the null hypothesis can be measured for a particular statistic considered in isolation (e.g. $p$-value [the probability that the null hypothesis would produce the observed result or greater]) that we use to test the hypothesis.

Basically, what I'm wondering is if it has been proven that the act of letting the number of hypotheses tested increase with sample size in some fashion (e.g. $n=N/2$ or $n=\sqrt{N}$) inevitably produces false positives.

Comment: If an event has a fixed positive probability in every try, then the probability that it will eventually happen, is $1$

Comment: Might you be mixing the Law of Large Numbers (convergence to a point) with the Central Limit Theorem (convergence to normal distribution)? Sorry, but your highlighted statement seems to me  imprecise or wrong.

Comment: Do you mean that according to CLT, when you'll take infinitely many samples then with strictly positive probability you will have a statistic that is far away from $\mu$ as you like?

Comment: @V.Vancak yes to the 'statistic as far from its true value as you like', no to "according to the CLT." CLT/LLN are only included because I'm not interested in statistics that trivially diverge (e.g. $X$ Gaussian distributed, $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i$ diverges).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem

Answer (score 1):

Let $p>0$ the probability of type $I$ error in one test and assume that $X$ counts the number of false-positives. Assume independence for mathematical inconvenience, then for $n$ tests, $X_n \sim Bin(n,p)$, so 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n \ge 1) = 1 - \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n = 0)=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-p)^n = 1.
$$